Android: Как изменить версию чужого APK-файла (в самом файле, с компа)?
Есть приложение из Google Play Market, и оно работало нормально. Но недавно оно самообновилось и перестало работать.
Хочу установить более старую версию обратно, но просто удалять приложение нельзя - потому что там важные пользовательские данные пропадут.
А система не даёт установить старую версию поверх новой. Root'а нету и не получится.
Может можно как-то подделать номер версии в самом файле APK? Чтоб система дала установить чуть более старый APK поверх более нового?
Спасибо!

Не выйдет - при изменении чего-либо в APK нарушится его "целостность", то есть его контент не будет соответствовать подписи. А для правильной подписи нужен ключ разработчика - иначе Андроид опять откажется устанавливать его поверх существующего.
